# pointer to function wont work

Tags: c++, c, pointers, function-pointers

I'm trying to learn how to use pointer to function properly. I was supposed to make a pointer to the function `strcmp`, inside the function `check`, but the program opens and closes immediately. As far as I understood, the pointer to function is correct on my code  `returnType (*pointer)(parameters));`   So what is going wrong? Thanks in advance.

```
void check(char *a,char *b,int (*cmp)(const char*,const char*))
{
    printf("Testing equality\n");
    if(!(*cmp)(a,b)) printf("equals");
    else printf("different");
}

int main(void)
{
    char s1[80] = "daniel" ,s2[80] = "daniel";
    int (*p)(const char*,const char*);
    p = strcmp();


    check(s1,s2,p);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Didn't the compiler warn you on this `p = strcmp();`?

Comment: Which compiler compiles this successfully `p = strcmp();`? And ***how?***

Comment: Did you add a declaration of `strcmp` yourself to make it compile? (You could just say `check(s1, s2, strcmp)`.)

Answer (score 8):

This line is incorrect:

```
p = strcmp();
```

Here you're **calling** `strcmp` with zero arguments, which is invalid. You should have gotten a very clear compiler error about this. For instance, gcc gives me:

> error: too few arguments to function ‘`int strcmp(const char*, const char*)`’

You want to just **assign** `strcmp`:

```
p = strcmp;
```

Also, you don't need to dereference function pointers to call them, so `!(*cmp)(a,b)` could be simplified to `!cmp(a,b)`.

Comment: Ye the way the book was teaching, it should be p = strcmp; without the (), but codeblocks wouldnt let me, so i added the (), and just got a warning 
|10|warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]|

Comment: with p = strcmp; the error is : " strcmp undeclared"

Comment: @DanielBezerradeMenezes Did you [`#include <cstring>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcmp)?

Comment: Omg im so dumb, sorry guys , the problem was that #includes where side by side............ like #include<stdio.h> #include<cstring>.